# Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction

Tags: jpa, connection, eclipselink, weblogic12c

Sometimes I met following exception while use JPA to call stored procedure. My connection is maintained by WebLogic connection pool.

```
<Mar 24, 2017 5:45:30 PM HKT> <Notice> <EclipseLink> <BEA-2005000> <2017-03-24 17:45:30.213--UnitOfWork(618601803)--Communication failure detected when attempting to perform read query outside of a transaction. Attempting to retry query.> 
<Mar 24, 2017 5:45:30 PM HKT> <Warning> <EclipseLink> <BEA-2005000> <2017-03-24 17:45:30.213--UnitOfWork(618601803)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.1.2.v20101206-r8635): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Unexpected exception while enlisting XAConnection java.sql.SQLException: XA error: XAResource.XAER_RMERR start() failed on resource 'weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource': XAER_RMERR : A resource manager error has occured in the transaction branch

oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1110)
    at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.start(OracleXAResource.java:240)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.start(DataSource.java:811)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.start(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1250)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.xaStart(XAServerResourceInfo.java:1183)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.XAServerResourceInfo.enlist(XAServerResourceInfo.java:286)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:561)
    at weblogic.transaction.internal.ServerTransactionImpl.enlistResource(ServerTransactionImpl.java:488)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1706)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1610)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnectionInternal(DataSource.java:499)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:483)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:527)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:513)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.reconnect(DatasourceAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.reconnect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.incrementCallCount(DatasourceAccessor.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2913)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1364)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1364)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1364)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1364)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1273)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:745)
    at com.xxxx.frm.numgen.NumberGeneratorAgentImpl$5.run(NumberGeneratorAgentImpl.java:392)
    at com.xxxx.frm.numgen.NumberGeneratorAgentImpl$5.run(NumberGeneratorAgentImpl.java:380)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAReadTransactionBlock.read(FWJPAReadTransactionBlock.java:88)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAReadTransaction.internalExecute(FWJPAReadTransaction.java:152)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAReadTransaction.execute(FWJPAReadTransaction.java:91)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAReadTransactionBlock.executeWithResult(FWJPAReadTransactionBlock.java:117)
    at com.xxxx.frm.numgen.NumberGeneratorAgentImpl.checkInstanceExist(NumberGeneratorAgentImpl.java:380)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.generator.SeqNumGenerator.getSeqNum(SeqNumGenerator.java:14)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.generator.BasicRefNumGenerator.generate(BasicRefNumGenerator.java:23)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.profile.AbstractSubmissionProfile.getRefNum(AbstractSubmissionProfile.java:21)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.profile.SubmissionProfileManager.generateReferenceNumber(SubmissionProfileManager.java:15)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.createSubmissionRequest(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:2094)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.generateSubmissionRequest(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:1029)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.access$000(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:176)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl$3.run(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:971)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl$3.run(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:967)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAWriteTransactionBlock.write(FWJPAWriteTransactionBlock.java:135)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAWriteTransaction.internalExecute(FWJPAWriteTransaction.java:621)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAWriteTransaction.execute(FWJPAWriteTransaction.java:423)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAWriteTransactionBlock.executeWithResult(FWJPAWriteTransactionBlock.java:178)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.manifestSubmission(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:967)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30734.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.xxxx.csc.frm.soa.rest.FWRestMethodUtil.executeMethod(FWRestMethodUtil.java:199)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.FWSubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.manifestSubmission(FWSubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:675)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30733.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:92)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.invoke(EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:140)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:171)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:708)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:103)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:311)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:336)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.xxxx.frm.art.filter.ARTFilter.doFilter(ARTFilter.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.enlist(DataSource.java:1711)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.refreshXAConnAndEnlist(DataSource.java:1610)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnectionInternal(DataSource.java:499)
    at weblogic.jdbc.jta.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:483)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:527)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:513)
    at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.connectInternal(DatasourceAccessor.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.connectInternal(DatabaseAccessor.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.reconnect(DatasourceAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.reconnect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.incrementCallCount(DatasourceAccessor.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:526)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeNonCursor(DataReadQuery.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataReadQuery.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:740)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataReadQuery.execute(DataReadQuery.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:643)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2913)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1291)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1364)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1364)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1364)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1364)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1273)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1247)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeReadQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:745)
    at com.xxxx.frm.numgen.NumberGeneratorAgentImpl$5.run(NumberGeneratorAgentImpl.java:392)
    at com.xxxx.frm.numgen.NumberGeneratorAgentImpl$5.run(NumberGeneratorAgentImpl.java:380)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAReadTransactionBlock.read(FWJPAReadTransactionBlock.java:88)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAReadTransaction.internalExecute(FWJPAReadTransaction.java:152)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAReadTransaction.execute(FWJPAReadTransaction.java:91)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAReadTransactionBlock.executeWithResult(FWJPAReadTransactionBlock.java:117)
    at com.xxxx.frm.numgen.NumberGeneratorAgentImpl.checkInstanceExist(NumberGeneratorAgentImpl.java:380)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.generator.SeqNumGenerator.getSeqNum(SeqNumGenerator.java:14)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.generator.BasicRefNumGenerator.generate(BasicRefNumGenerator.java:23)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.profile.AbstractSubmissionProfile.getRefNum(AbstractSubmissionProfile.java:21)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.profile.SubmissionProfileManager.generateReferenceNumber(SubmissionProfileManager.java:15)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.createSubmissionRequest(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:2094)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.generateSubmissionRequest(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:1029)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.access$000(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:176)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl$3.run(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:971)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl$3.run(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:967)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAWriteTransactionBlock.write(FWJPAWriteTransactionBlock.java:135)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAWriteTransaction.internalExecute(FWJPAWriteTransaction.java:621)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAWriteTransaction.execute(FWJPAWriteTransaction.java:423)
    at com.xxxx.frm.transaction.FWJPAWriteTransactionBlock.executeWithResult(FWJPAWriteTransactionBlock.java:178)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.manifestSubmission(SubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:967)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30734.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.xxxx.csc.frm.soa.rest.FWRestMethodUtil.executeMethod(FWRestMethodUtil.java:199)
    at com.xxxx.yyy.cdm.smm.service.FWSubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.manifestSubmission(FWSubmissionServicePortTypeImpl.java:675)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30733.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:92)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSInstanceResolver$WLSInvoker.invoke(WLSInstanceResolver.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:151)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.invoke(EndpointMethodHandlerImpl.java:268)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:866)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:815)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:778)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:680)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:403)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:539)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:253)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:140)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.WLSServletAdapter.handle(WLSServletAdapter.java:171)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$AuthorizedInvoke.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:708)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:363)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:146)
    at weblogic.wsee.util.ServerSecurityHelper.authenticatedInvoke(ServerSecurityHelper.java:103)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter$3.run(HttpServletAdapter.java:311)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.HttpServletAdapter.post(HttpServletAdapter.java:336)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.JAXWSServlet.doRequest(JAXWSServlet.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.http.AbstractAsyncServlet.service(AbstractAsyncServlet.java:99)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at com.xxxx.frm.art.filter.ARTFilter.doFilter(ARTFilter.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:60)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3748)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3714)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2182)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1491)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:263)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Error Code: 0
Call: BEGIN FRM_NGS_PKG.checkEntryExist(i_numgenid=>?, o_exist=>?); END;
    bind => [CDM_TW_OB_REF_NUM_xxxx, => exist]
Query: ValueReadQuery()>
```

Comment: Check your transaction settings, as you have misconfigured things.  The error states you are trying to perform reads outside of a transaction, but have configured JPA to use a JTA datasource that only allows connections within a transaction.

Comment: Everything back to normal after we restart weblogic, still no clue about root cause